# how to detect what triggered the close event in jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have Create and Cancel buttons as part of a jquery-ui modal dialog.  I want to do certain thing after closing the dialog only if the user clicks "Create".  If they click "Cancel", or "X" or press Esc, I want to do something else.  Is there a way to pass parameters to the close event handler or some other way to detect what caused the close?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this as discribed here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

-- edit

copied from the link from above:

```
    var trigger = "";
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        buttons: {
            'Create': function() {
                // do your stuff
                trigger = "create";
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
        close: function() {
            if (trigger == "create")
                // do something here
        }
    });
```

Comment: right, I'm wondering how I can detect inside the close handler what triggered it.

Comment: mh, on the top of my head- declare a var trigger = ""; as global and set it in the 'Create' function. Than you can get the value in the close handler...

Comment: Hmmm. Obviously this won't work if you set `autoOpen:false` and open the dialog box twice.

Answer (score 6):

In the close event you can tell what happened by looking at the *event* parameter (parameter 1).

If the dialog was closed by clicking the **[x]** then you get **mouse-event** fields.

Similarly, if the dialog was closed by pressing **Escape** then you get **keyboard-event** fields.

If the dialog was closed programmatically then neither of the above apply.

So, a good place to start is to look at *event.which*.  Closing with the **[x]** will mean you get the mouse button value (1 to 3), and closing with **Escape** will mean you get the key code (27). Closing programmatically means event.which will be undefined.

Now back to your question...

You want to do one thing if they press Create - that's easy, just put it in the function for that button.

You want to do something else on [x], Escape or clicking Cancel.  Create a function called *cancelled()* (or whatever) and then call that function on the Cancel button AND call it in the close event *if event.which has a value*.

Something like this...

```
buttons: {
    'Create': function() {
        // do your stuff here
        $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        cancelled();
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
},
close: function(event) {
    if (event.which) {
        cancelled();
    }
}
```

I think that covers what you need, and it avoids having to mess around creating a variable to keep track of where you've been.

Comment: Really worked for me. Thank you! I hope someday they build something into the dialog that would detect the source.

Answer (score 4):

Define events for your buttons like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Create': function() {
                alert('the user clicked create');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                alert('the user clicked cancel');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
           // do somthing

        }
});
```

Also take a look at the parameters passed into the close event, the method signature is:

```
function(event, ui)
```

You can find more info here [link text](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#events)

Comment: right, I'm wondering how I can detect inside the close handler what triggered it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#jqPopup').dialog({modal:true,title:tit,autoOpen:false,beforeclose:function(){
   //Will get triggered when user press the 'X' button 
   $("#wholeContent").css('display','block');} 
});

$("#wholeContent").css('display','none');

$('#jqPopup').dialog('open');
```